# "expecting endmodule" error, can't understand why?

Tags: fpga, verilog, intel-fpga

I'm trying to build a counter with a-sync reset, that will be shown on the 7-segment display on the fpga board.
I saw a few posts about my problem:

> "near text "if"; expecting endmodule"

But still I can't understand  why I'm getting that error, I know that I am missing an important rule, but I can't figure it out.

```
module up_counter(
input clk,rst,  
output segA, segB, segC, segD, segE ,segF , segG, segDP);
reg [3:0] BCD;

always @(posedge clk);
    reg [7:0] SevenSeg;
    if (BCD==4'h9) begin 
        BCD <= 4'h0;
        SevenSeg = 8'b11111100;
    end else if (rst==0) begin
        BCD <= 4'h0;
        SevenSeg = 8'b11111100;
    end else begin
        BCD <= BCD+4'h1;
        always @(*)
           case(BCD)
              4'h0:SevenSeg = 8'b11111100;//0
              4'h1:SevenSeg = 8'b01100000;//1
              4'h2:SevenSeg = 8'b11011010;//2
              4'h3:SevenSeg = 8'b11110010;
              4'h4:SevenSeg = 8'b01100110;
              4'h5:SevenSeg = 8'b10110110;
              4'h6:SevenSeg = 8'b10111110;
              4'h7:SevenSeg = 8'b11100000;
              4'h8:SevenSeg = 8'b11111110;
              4'h9:SevenSeg = 8'b11110110;
           default: SevenSeg = 8'b11100000;
           endcase
    end

assign {segA, segB, segC, segD, segE ,segF , segG, segDP} = SevenSeg;

endmodule
```

This "always" addition came after , I read that case and if statments need to come with always,but this didn't help.
   always @(*)
   case(BCD)
Furthur more, i tried to put an "always" before the :
    if (BCD==4'h9) begin 
But then I got the same error:

> "near text "always"; expecting endmodule"

I feel so limited, because at this moment every time I had an "if" , I get an error, so I'm missing here a serious and basic rule.
Thanks a lot,I really appriciate your help.

Thank your all for your help, I think I did , every imporve you gave me, and this is the improve code:

```
module up_counter(
input clk,rst,
output segA, segB, segC, segD, segE ,segF , segG, segDP);
reg [3:0] BCD;
reg [7:0] SevenSeg;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
if (BCD==4'h9) begin 
   BCD <= 4'h0;
   SevenSeg = 8'b11111100;
end else if (rst==0) begin
   BCD <= 4'h0;
   SevenSeg = 8'b11111100;
end

else begin
   BCD <= BCD+4'h1;
   case(BCD)
     4'h0:SevenSeg <= 8'b11111100;//0
     4'h1:SevenSeg <= 8'b01100000;//1
     4'h2:SevenSeg <= 8'b11011010;//2
     4'h3:SevenSeg <= 8'b11110010;
     4'h4:SevenSeg <= 8'b01100110;
     4'h5:SevenSeg <= 8'b10110110;
     4'h6:SevenSeg <= 8'b10111110;
     4'h7:SevenSeg <= 8'b11100000;
     4'h8:SevenSeg <= 8'b11111110;
     4'h9:SevenSeg <= 8'b11110110;
     default: SevenSeg <= 8'b11100000;
endcase
end
end
assign {segA, segB, segC, segD, segE ,segF , segG, segDP} = SevenSeg;

endmodule
```

It did resolve the problem I had, but now, I get only 8 in the 7-segments display, is there any more rules Im missing.

Comment: Without proper indenting, your HDL is much harder to read than necessary.

Comment: My wild guess is that your `end if (rst==0) begin` was meant to be an `else if`.

Comment: Thank you for the addvice, but that wasn't the problem, the "else" fell when i pasted, and organized the code.

Comment: Remove the ; from the end of the `always` line.

Comment: What is at the end of the line that it tells you about that shouldn't be there?

Comment: Also, what is inside an always block that shouldn't be there? (Hint `reg`, `always`)

Comment: Also, don't mix blocking and non blocking assignments in the same always block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. The semicolon at the end of the first `always` line means the whole `if` structure that follows isn't inside the always block.
2. You have a second `always` block nested insider your first one. There's no need to do that. Since you already are inside an `always` block, a multiplexer will be inferred from your `case` statement even without another `always`.

   The `always @(*)` construct is used when you want to produce a combinatorial multiplexer --- meaning you want to be able to access the unlatched multiplexer outputs. Since you're immediately latching the mux outputs here, there's no need for this.
3. You can't (AFAIK, but I'm not up on the latest Verilog revisions) declare new signals (`reg` or `wire` declarations) inside an always block. Move your declaration of `SevenSeg` to the top of the module.

Style note: Use `begin` and `end` inside every `always`, even if you will only have one statement in the block. It makes it easier to follow the code, and avoids mistakes when you edit the code later.